# Prevent a unit to be automatically added to the Uses clause?

Tags: delphi, alphablending, jedi-code-library

I am using TJvTransparentForm (from Project JEDI) on one of my forms. I am also using AlphaControls for my entire project. The problem is, TJvTransparentForm does not work well with the unit "acPNG" from AlphaControls. I need to use the regular PNG class (?).

I tried using an UnregisterClass routine (or something, dont remember what it was), and that didn't do it.

I also tried removing AlphaControls from my project, add the TImage, reenable AC, but it still generates the acPNG in the Uses clause.

What can I do?
Thanks!
- Jeff

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. If you mean - to exclude a unit, automatically included into "uses" at design time, when a component was droped on a form. Then the only way - create this component at run time.
2. If the unit was indirectly used by some linked library, then you cannot to exclude this unit. Or ... do not use the library.

Comment: It automatically gets added whenever I have a TImage on my form. The TPNGImage is replaced with TPNGGraphic, which is what I am trying to prevent.

Comment: Also, not using the library is not an option. And since I am storing my image in a TPicture at design time, I cant create the image at runtime, unless I load from a file I guess.

Comment: @Jeff: You can load it from the .exe's resources.

Comment: @Jeff It's almost always better to store such things as resources than in the .dfm. Once they get into the .dfm it can be hard to manage them.

Comment: well, I tried using my own method 2 (Remove package, add it back), apparently I just had to add back the pngimage unit first. Anyways, this gets market as answer, as it gives good suggestions!

Answer (score 0):

Another option is moved the desired unit after the other

Cheers

Comment: I already tried that, it didn't work, weird enough. I could try again though, will report back when I get home :)